# Стакан чи склянка?

Tags: росіянізм, розмовна-українська, суржик

На сайті ukr-mova.in.ua в розділі антисуржик знайшов картинку на якій було зображено, що замість слова "стакан" потрібно вживати слово "склянка". Однак на сайті Вікіпедії пише: "...скляну посудину для рідини називати "склянкою", а посудини схожої форми з іншого матеріалу - "стаканами"". Хоч на сайті Академічного тлумачного словнику є як і слово "стакан", так і слово "склянка", і значення у них одинакові (окрім того, що останнє має ще й значення проміжку часу та старовинного суднового піскового годинника).
Отже якщо ми використаємо слово "стакан", наприклад, у творі ЗНО це не вважатиметься помилкою? І як в такому випадку називати, для прикладу, залізні чи глиняні стакани?

Comment: які саме значення має "стакан", яких не має "склянка"? уточніть це у запитанні, будь ласка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C/) радять

> Замініть іменник **стакан**, якщо мовиться про скляний посуд, на
>   стилістично кращий варіант: **склянка**.

В [експрес уроках](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gedP9bjiYkc) Олександр Авраменко рекомендує вживати слово **склянка**, не залежно з якого матеріалу виготовлена посуда.

З СУМ-11 присутні обидва слова та мають однакові значення:

> ***[СКЛЯНКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/skljanka)*** **1.** Скляна посудина циліндричної форми, без ручки,
>   признач. для пиття, зберігання рідини і т. ін.**//**  чого. Така посудина,
>   наповнена чим-небудь; кількість чогось, що вміщається в такій
>   посудині.**//**  рідко. Взагалі скляна посудина, банка і т. ін. **2**. *військ.*
>   Гільза, в якій міститься заряд артилерійського снаряда. **3.** техн. Назва
>   деяких пристроїв, деталей і т. ін., що мають циліндричну форму.
>
> ***[СТАКАН](http://sum.in.ua/s/stakan)*** **1.** Скляна посудина циліндричної форми, без ручки, признач.
>   для пиття, зберігання рідини і т. ін.; склянка. **//**  Така посудина,
>   наповнена чим-небудь; кількість чогось, що вміщається в ній. **2.**
>   *військ.* Гільза артилерійського снаряда. **3.** *техн.* Назва деяких деталей
>   спеціального призначення, що мають циліндричну форму.

***Обидва слова можемо вживати, як тотожні (слово "стакан" у творі ЗНО не повинне бути помилкою).  Хоча, на мою думку, краще вживати слово "склянка" воно звичніше. Наприклад, глиняні та залізні склянки.***

Comment: То як слід казати: паперовий стакан чи паперова склянка?

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov паперова склянка