# Підсклянник чи підстаканник?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

На сайті є питання - [Стакан чи склянка?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) відповідно до відповіді краще вживати слово "склянка".

Як бути зі словами підстаканник та підсклянник? 
Обидва слова є в СУМ-11, проте слово ["підсклянник"](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidskljannyk) на відміну від ["підстаканник"](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidstakannyk) має позначено *рідко*.

То яке з цих слів краще вживати в усному мовлені та на письмі?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проф. Пономарів радить вживати слово **підсклянник**:

> Під негативним упливом російської мови в технічних значеннях частіше вживали слова **стакан**. Науковий стиль, як відомо, характеризується чітким нормуванням мовних засобів. Тому в технічній термінології слід віддавати перевагу слову **склянка**. З огляду на це й підставку з ручкою для цієї посудини варто називати не **підстаканник** (як чуємо й читаємо в засобах масової інформації), а **підсклянник** (це слово зафіксоване багатьма словниками української мови).

На сайті [onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA/) також знаходимо, що стилістично кращий варіант слово **підсклянник**:

> Замініть іменник **підстаканник** на стилістично кращий варіант: **підсклянник**.

На основі цих джерел можна зробити висновок, що на письмі, особливо в науковому тилі краще вживати **підсклянник**.